# Sendgrid email message with Next.js

Tags: typescript, next.js, fetch, authorization, sendgrid

Hi could you please help me to solve this issue.

I'm using sendgrid to send an email message when user submits a form.

When I add my gmail, I receive the email message. If I add my company email, I don't receive any email message.

I have googled this issue and they advised to add an *authorization header*.  I added this but am still getting the same error.

Below is my code

```js
const onIfuRequestSubmit: SubmitHandler < IFURequest > = async data => {
    process.env.PSU_API_MAIL_ENDPOINT ? ? "https://universal.company.com/gw/v1/mail",
      await fetch('/api/emailIFU', {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.PSU_API_KEY}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      })
```

Comment: Can you please add the implementation of your `/api/emailIFU` endpoint? Also, are you using gmail/your company email as a sender or recipient of the email?